# How do I return Eloqent Models instead of an array when using LengthAwarePaginator?

Tags: php, laravel

### Some Context

I have a page where I need to show a paginated list of posts. Before now, my controller was:

```
$posts = Post::whereNotNull('published_at')->paginate(10);

return view('index', compact('posts'));
```

Then in my view `index.blade.php` I could do something like:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <h3 class="mb-4"><a href="{{$post->link}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h3>
@endforeach
```

Now I need to limit the query to only 50 posts. However, the below code snippet fails since laravel pagination uses limit internally which overrides my own query. So I still get all the posts in the database:

```
$posts = Post::whereNotNull('published_at')->limit(50)->paginate(10);

return view('index', compact('posts'));
```

### My Problem

So I used the `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` to create a manual paginator. So now my controller looks like:

```
$page = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

$perPage = 10;

$results = Post::whereNotNull('published_at')->limit(50)->get();

$items = array_slice($results->toArray(), ($page - 1) * $perPage, $perPage);

$posts = new LengthAwarePaginator($items, count($results), $perPage, $page);

return view('index', compact('posts'));
```

My `index.blade.php` remains the same. But now if I try to visit the page, I get an error like

```
Trying to get property 'link' of non-object
```

It turns out that in my `index.blade.php`, each `$post` in `$posts` is an array instead of an instance of the `Post` class.

### My Question

How can I get each `$post` in `$posts` to be an object (an instance of the `Post` class)? Ideally, I would like the view to work just the way it is without modification.

I appreciate all the efforts.

Comment: You're the one doing the conversion by running `$results->toArray()`.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator) pointed me towards that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Laravel's `Collection` object](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) has many built-in methods to act like an array. Instead of converting your results to an an array and using `array_slice`:

```php
$items = array_slice($results->toArray(), ($page - 1) * $perPage, $perPage);
```

You should use [the `Collection::slice()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-slice).

```php
$items = $results->slice(($page - 1) * $perPage, $perPage);
```